# What should I add to ListPlot to make result transparent?

Tags: plotting, opacity

(* Plot shows two overlapping data sets. I want to see all data by making them transparent. What should I add to ListPlot to make data transparent ?  *)

```
A = Table[{xfinalpion[i], zfinalpion[i]}, {i, Nphot}];
B = Table[{xfinalKaon[i], zfinalKaon[i]}, {i, Nphot}];
ListPlot[{A, B}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.005], 
FrameLabel -> {"xfinal", "zfinal"}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 0.5, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
PlotRange -> {{80., 88.}, {9.5, 14.0}}]
```

Comment: Something like this? `A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 150];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 150];
ListPlot[{A, B}, FrameLabel -> {"xfinal", "zfinal"}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{AbsolutePointSize[12], Opacity[0.5]}]]
`

Comment: I added: PlotStyle -> Directive[{AbsolutePointSize[12], Opacity[0.5]}]. That does not do it.

Comment: Have you tried my example?

Comment: Make sure that you have a single `PlotStyle` option; your code has two. Also make sure that the `PointSize` is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Benefitting from the comments:

```
Nphot = 20;
aa = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {Nphot, 2}];
bb = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {Nphot, 2}];
```

- I have used `PlotRange -> Automatic` but you can change that for your particular case back to what it was. Use lower case letters (preferably).
- Separate `PlotStyle` for each set of data (not necessary in general but I think you want two plot styles for your data sets)

---

```
ListPlot[{aa, bb}
 , PlotStyle -> {
   {Brown, Opacity[0.5], PointSize[0.07]}
   , {Lighter@Red, Opacity[0.5], PointSize[0.02]}
   }
 , FrameLabel -> {"xfinal", "zfinal"}
 , Axes -> False
 , Frame -> True
 , AspectRatio -> 0.5
 , PlotRange -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work. I tried: A = Table[{xfinalpion[i], zfinalpion[i]}, {i, Nphot}];
B = Table[{xfinalKaon[i], zfinalKaon[i]}, {i, Nphot}];
ListPlot[{A, B}, {Brown, Opacity[0.5], 
  PointSize[0.005]} , {Lighter@Red, Opacity[0.5], PointSize[0.005]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"xfinal", "zfinal"}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5,
 PlotRange -> {{80., 88.}, {9.5, 14.0}}]

Comment: I had error. Thanks for help